# why sort works on associate array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am just wondering why this is working the way it does. I have a multi dimensional associative array and when I apply sort it is sorting by the name?

```
$data[] = array(
    'name' => $row2['name'],
    'email' => $row2['email'],
    'phone' => $row2['phone'],
    'org' => $row2['org']
);

sort($data);
echo '<xmp>';
print_R($data);
echo '</xmp>';
```

Comment: *"it is sorting by the name?"* --- Your result being?

Comment: Can you provide intended and received results?

Comment: i guess it's sorted by the first array's value, which is `name` in this case

Comment: One entry sorted by... itself...?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#54903

Comment: Wouldn't happen to have anything to do with [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20505517/), now would it?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `sort()` on a multi-dimensional array unless you want this behavior:

1. The arrays are sorted by comparison with the shorter array being the smallest
2. If they are the same length and if they don't have the same keys then they are uncomparable
3. If they are the same length and if the key exists (name in this example) in both arrays, then the array with the smallest value for that key is the smallest
4. Repeat 3 for additional keys